# How to retrieve from firebase database and display in an EditText?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to retrieve from my database to display it on my Android app but it does not seem to work at all!

Here is the code I tried with but no luck at all!

```
 mRef = new Firebase("https://uevent-f8ea1.firebaseio.com/New Vendors" + useridstring + "/name"  );

    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            DisplayName.setText(value);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });[Database Structure][1]
```

Comment: Could you post your json structure?

Comment: @KurtAcosta I honestly dont know how to do it but basically the db structure is like New Vendors ---> UID ---> name

Comment: You can get the JSON as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: You're using a very old version if the Firebase SDK. I highly recommend starting with the latest SDK. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) and [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found the json file idk how to open it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you missed a slash on this part:

```
mRef = new Firebase("https://uevent-f8ea1.firebaseio.com/New Vendors/" + useridstring + "/name"  );
```

Try this code out and see if it works for you.

Comment: Glad I could help! Try to work on @Frank's suggestion, though. Use the latest Firebase SDK.